# Getting Milliseconds in groovy

Tags: java, groovy

If i have code like this:

```
def yourDate= new GregorianCalendar( 2010, Calendar.OCTOBER, 1 )
        SimpleDateFormat date=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        def d=date.parse(yourDate);
```

is there any function in groovy which can give me  milliseconds?

Comment: Why do you need to parse the `calendar` in the first place?

Answer (score 13):

there are 2 ways to do it :

```
def date1= new Date()
    println date1.getTime()

def date2= System.currentTimeMillis()
 println date2
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a date object, you can do:

```
def mills = date.parse(yourDate).getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

**I guess i found the answer:**

```
def yourDate= new GregorianCalendar( 2010, Calendar.OCTOBER, 1 )
        println(yourDate.getTimeInMillis());
```